# What is $\partial_t g^{ij}(t)$?

Tags: differential-geometry

This is probably a dumb question; so far, I have been using $g^{ij}g_{ij} = n$ as granted, but I am probably doing something wrong here. Suppose that $g_{ij}(t)$ is a time-evolving metric. Let $h_{ij} = \partial_t g_{ij}(t)$. In order to find $\partial_t(g^{ij})$, I need to do:

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  &\quad \partial_t (g^{ij}g_{jk}) &&= 0 \\
  \Leftrightarrow& \quad g_{jk}(\partial_tg^{ij}) + g^{ij}(\partial_t g_{jk}) &&= 0 \\
  \Leftrightarrow& \quad g_{jk}(\partial_tg^{ij}) &&= -g^{ij}(\partial_t g_{jk}) = -g^{ij} h_{jk} = -h^i_k
\end{alignat*}
At this step, standard thing would be to multiply each side by $g^{kl}$ so that I get $\partial_t g^{il} = -h^{il}$. However, what happens if I multiply by $g^{jk}$?

\begin{alignat*}{2}
& g^{jk}g_{jk}(\partial_tg^{ij}) && = -g^{jk}h^i_k \\
\Leftrightarrow \quad&  n(\partial_t g^{ij}) = -h^{ij}
\end{alignat*}

I am assuming the former is clearly right. But I don't see an error with multiplying both sides by $g^{jk}$ instead of $g^{kl}$. What is the error that I am making?

Comment: you are already summing over $j$, so you cannot just mulitply by $g^{jk}$ ($j$ is no longer a free index)

Comment: @thomas So is it a general rule of thumb to avoid multiple contractions over one index? (for example, I am doing two contractions over $k$ at the same time)

Comment: One way to check whether you are doing the contractions correctly is to write out the formulas in dimensions $n=2$ and $n=3$ without using either the Einstein summation convention or summation signs.

Comment: If you have an expression like $t^{ij}s_{jk}$, then the resulting expression (which would look something like $r^{i}_k$) has no longer any dependency on the index which was used in the sum. If that is not clear to you, then, as suggested by @Deane it might be a good idea to write this down explicitly in small dimensions.

Comment: The above comments said it all on your mistake in the computations. But I would like to add that since $g^{ij}(t)$ are the coefficients of the inverse matrix of $g_{ij}(t)$, you can find out the result by looking at the derivative of $[M(t)]^{-1}$ where $M$ is a $C^1$ family of invertible matrices. This is something like $-M(t)^{-1} M'(t)M(t)^{-1}$ if I remember well.